# Does the ``-'' sign have meaning in rsyslog.conf

Tags: configuration, rsyslog

Rsyslog is backwards-compatible with Syslog configuration files.

The syslog.conf man page has:

> You may prefix each entry with the
>   minus ``-'' sign to omit syncing the
>   file after every logging. Note that
>   you might lose information if the
>   system crashes right behind a write
>   attempt. Nevertheless this might give
>   you back some performance, especially
>   if you run programs that use logging
>   in a very verbose manner.

but I could not find aything about the `-` sign in `man rsyslog.conf`.

What does rsyslog do when if reads `-` in the config file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has the same function. [Docs](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_actions.html) ([cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8bC3RKktwj0J:www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_actions.html), since the original is returning an error right now)